# Cannot fetch Facebook uploaded images

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api

```
func fetchListOfUserPhotos() {
   // let graphRequest = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "picture"])
    graphRequest.start(completionHandler: { [self] (_, result, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error as Any)
        } else {
            print(result)
        }
    })

}
```

getting empty data.. please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I got empty result when I fetch all uploaded images from Facebook... previously its working fine. I din't change any code suddenly I found nil result.